# Two developer licenses under the same Apple ID (same company)

Tags: developer-program, license

We already have one developer license, but want to buy one more developer license.

Is it possible under the same Apple ID? 
We want to buy one more license under same company name, same Apple ID. 
Basically Apple ID (having agent role) is legal owner. So under the same Apple ID, we wanted to buy a 2nd license.

If no, what are the alternate ways?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible with the same Apple ID.

You can simply just create a new Apple ID, then join the developer program (as Individual), then your company can invite you to the team as a developer. You will have access to the tools and profiles just like user #1.

Every time you log in you will be asked if you want to be logged into your Individual account, or your company account you are apart of, just choose the company team.

**Note:** Your company account needs to be a entity type, 'Company / Organization'. This will not work for entity type 'Individual'.  As an 'Individual' count as 1, you can't have any other members.